# How to get all terms in index directory created by lucene 4.4.0

Tags: java, lucene

I's using lucene 4.4 for index my docs, and now I want to get all terms by IndexReader. In older version I used:

```
IndexReader reader = new IndexReader.open(pathIndexDirectory);
TermEnum listTerm = reader.terms();
```

But in version 4.4 I can't do it.
What can I do now ?

Comment: And i also need it :))

Answer (score 8):

So I'm using this way:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(ramdir)
Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
        for (String field : fields) {
            Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
            TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
            int count = 0;
            while (termsEnum.next() != null) {
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
```

Comment: You can also use terms.size() to get the total amount of terms for the current field without having to execute the while loop.

Comment: Wouldn't this count common terms several times?